# how to find in which file shipping method text is present

Tags: shipping-methods

In checkout, we can see "Shipping method" text, i want to hide that text, so

using template path hints, i searched in below files

```
frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml

frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/progress/shipping.phtml

frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/additional.phtml

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml
```

but i found 2 times in

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml
```

i removed in 2 places, but still that text is displaying.

```
<?php if ($this->getCheckout()->getStepData('shipping_method', 'complete')): ?>
<dt class="complete">
    <?php echo $this->__('Shipping Method') ?> <span class="changelink"><span class="separator">|</span> <a
        href="#shipping_method"
        onclick="checkout.changeSection('opc-shipping_method'); return false;"><?php echo $this->__('Change') ?></a></span>
</dt>
<dd class="complete">
    <?php if ($this->getShippingMethod()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getShippingDescription() ?>

    <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPriceExclTax(); ?>
    <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPriceInclTax(); ?>
    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()): ?>
        <?php echo $_incl; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $_excl; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
        (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('Shipping method has not been selected yet') ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</dd>
<?php else: ?>
<dt>
    <?php echo $this->__('Shipping Method') ?>
</dt>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Clear you cache as well as browser cache

Comment: yes, i done that.... let me try browser cache....

Comment: IF still this don't  works then enable template hints. You can see where the text is coming from

Comment: sorry, no luck.....

Comment: Harendar answer will remove shipping method block completely

Comment: @Rohit yes , i followed this to remove shipping method : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381970/magento-skip-shipping-method-on-checkout-page but only text was displaying. now its removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can creat new file as below path

app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage.php

and paste code as below ,

```
class Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Get 'one step checkout' step data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSteps()
    {
        $steps = array();
       //$stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');
       $stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'payment', 'review');


        if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
            $stepCodes = array_diff($stepCodes, array('login'));
        }

        foreach ($stepCodes as $step) {
            $steps[$step] = $this->getCheckout()->getStepData($step);
        }

        return $steps;
    }

    /**
     * Get active step
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getActiveStep()
    {
        return $this->isCustomerLoggedIn() ? 'billing' : 'login';
    }
}
```

Comment: i will try and let you know....